# How to display my polynomial regression line?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn, seaborn

My plot has a very fat line, which I didn't expect and haven't been able to troubleshoot on my own. I don't know how to show the image.

Doing EDA on Kaggle's Craigslist Auto data set. I want to display and then compare and contrast a linear and polynomial regression fit correlating price and model year for each unique vehicle make and model (i.e. Ford F150).

How do I do the following plot with a more normal looking line, line width doesn't change anything.

[image]

```
df_f150=df[df['Make and Model']=='ford F-150']

#plotting a linear regression line for each dataframe
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
sns.regplot(x=df_f150.year, y=df_f150.price, color='b')


'#Here is where I try to do one of the polynomial regressions'

# Legend, title and labels.
#plt.legend(labels=x)
plt.title('Relationship Between Model Year and Price', size=24)
plt.xlabel('Year', size=18)
plt.ylabel('Price', size=18)
plt.xlim(1990,2020)
plt.ylim(1000,100000)

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures 


X = df_f150['year'].values.reshape(-1,1)
y = df_f150['price'].values.reshape(-1,1)

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 8) 
poly.fit_transform(X) 

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

regressor = LinearRegression()  
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train) #training the algorithm

#To retrieve the intercept:
print(regressor.intercept_)
#For retrieving the slope:
print(regressor.coef_)

y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)

dfres = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test.flatten(), 'Predicted': y_pred.flatten()})
dfres

plt.scatter(X_test, y_test,  color='gray')
plt.plot(X_test, y_pred, color='red', linewidth=2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm finding your question unclear. Your code doesn't seem to match the picture you are showing, so it's difficult to understand where exactly you're having difficulties. Is it with the very tedious list of dataframe creation, with the long list of `regplot()` or with the output of the regression? Please only provide the *relevant* part of the code. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @DizietAsahi Thank you for the feedback, made some additional edits that hopefully clarify. Primarily looking to resolve the issues with plotting the output of the regression.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem unless you actually produce a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that is some code that one can copy and paste and that produces the problematic result.

Comment: That being said, it definitely looks like the root of the problem is that you are doing a `plot()` with unsorted x-values, so the line keeps zipping back and forth. I bet you need to sort X_test

Answer (score 1):

## First, always clean and check the data:

- Given data from [Kaggle: Vehicles listings from Craigslist.org](https://www.kaggle.com/austinreese/craigslist-carstrucks-data#craigslistVehiclesFull.csv)
- Incidentally, the plot generated by `sns.regplot` is nearly the same as that generated by performing the regression with `sklearn`.  As such, I have not included the additional code.

### Load and Select Data:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd


file = Path.cwd() / 'data/craigslist-carstrucks-data/craigslistVehicles.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(file, usecols=['price', 'year', 'manufacturer', 'make'])

 price    year manufacturer          make
  3500  2006.0    chevrolet           NaN
  3399  2002.0        lexus         es300
  9000  2009.0    chevrolet  suburban lt2
 31999  2012.0          ram          2500
 16990  2003.0          ram          3500

# Select specific data:
# outliers exist, so price < 120000 and f-150 began production in 1975
ford = df[['price', 'year']][(df.manufacturer == 'ford') & (df.make == 'f-150') & (df.price < 120000) & (df.year >= 1975)]

 price    year
  1600  1992.0
 39760  2018.0
 11490  2014.0
  2500  1993.0
 17950  2014.0
```

#### Plot with [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/):

- [`sns.regplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html?highlight=regplot#seaborn.regplot)

```py
import seaborn as sns

sns.regplot(x=ford.year, y=ford.price)
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Here is the plot, without removing outliers:

- The plot is flat because the max price is `8.888889e+07`

  - You set `plt.ylim(1000,100000)`, so the outliers didn't show up
- I made the arbitrary decision to exclude all prices above $120k, because I know that's an unrealistic price for this sample.
- Simply removing outliers is not always the best option.

[image]

```py
print(ford.describe())

              price          year
count  1.127000e+04  11270.000000
mean   2.405777e+04   2010.459184
std    8.372461e+05      6.454361
min    0.000000e+00   1975.000000
25%    5.300000e+03   2007.000000
50%    1.548750e+04   2012.000000
75%    2.549500e+04   2015.000000
max    8.888889e+07   2020.000000
```

#### Plot from performing the regression with `sklearn`

- [Linear Regression Example Plot](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-ols-py)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(X_test, y_test)
plt.plot(X_test, y_pred, color='violet', linewidth=3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Plot the `X_test` & `y_pred` in the `sns.regplot()`:

```py
sns.regplot(x=ford.year, y=ford.price)
sns.scatterplot(X_test.flatten(), y_pred.flatten(), color='r')
plt.show()
```

[image]